# warning: control may reach end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type] }

Tags: c++, chess

I am a beginner in c++ and I am trying to make a chess game and when I compile :

```
bool isValidMove(int inCol, int inRow, int outCol, int outRow, char board[8][8])
{
    if (board[inRow][inCol] == '-')
        return false;
    else
    {
        if((board[inRow][inCol] == 'R' || board[inRow][inCol] == 'r') && isValidMoveRook(inCol, inRow, outCol, outRow, board))
            return true;
        if((board[inRow][inCol] == 'K' || board[inRow][inCol] == 'k') && isValidMoveKnight(inCol, inRow, outCol, outRow, board))
            return true;   
        if((board[inRow][inCol] == 'R' || board[inRow][inCol] == 'r') && isValidMoveRook(inCol, inRow, outCol, outRow, board))
            return true;
    }
}
```

I get this warning from my compiler `warning: control may reach end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type] }`
can anyone help me with this problem by the way I am on the mac.

Comment: because your function may not return anything (what if none of the `if`s in the `else` branch evaluate to `true`?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't return anything at the very end if it doesn't go on your conditions.

```
bool isValidMove(int inCol, int inRow, int outCol, int outRow, char board[8][8]) {
     if(board[inRow][inCol] == '-') {
         return false;
 }
 else {
     if((board[inRow][inCol] == 'R' || board[inRow][inCol] == 'r') && isValidMoveRook(inCol, inRow, outCol, outRow, board)) {
     return true;
         }
         if((board[inRow][inCol] == 'K' || board[inRow][inCol] == 'k') && isValidMoveKnight(inCol, inRow, outCol, outRow, board)) {
             return true;
         }   
         if((board[inRow][inCol] == 'R' || board[inRow][inCol] == 'r')&&      isValidMoveRook(inCol, inRow, outCol, outRow, board)) {
             return true;
         }
     }
     // return something here
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `else` block there's a path through where nothing is returned. That's what you're being warned about.

Comment: can you tell me what path

Comment: @UnholySheep has already in comment to your question.

Comment: I don't get it though because the if returns false and the else returns true